# Within Azure DevOps, in a Scrum project, change the work type label from "product backlog item" to "user story"

Tags: azure, configuration, devops, scrum

Default hierarchy in ADO using SCRUM config option is epic>feature>product backlog item>task. This is causing confusion for my teams (confusion = waste). I would like to change it to epic>feature>user story>task. This is the default when configuring in "agile" but not in "scrum".

I have watched a 2 hour video that mentions that at the org level you can change it, but it does not show where. I have parsed through all the configuration pages and I did find "work item type" with an ellipsis... but only option was to delete. I expected to see "product backlog item" but it was not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Yes, this is achievable by tweaking the Organization Settings. You can find it on the landing page of your organization: `https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}`

[image: Org Settings]

Or you may also directly navigate to: `https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}/_settings/process` to browse through the Process settings for your organization.

You will find **Agile**, **Basic**, **Scrum**, and **CMMI** listed within, which are System processes, and hence are locked from being changed. What you can now do is to create an *inherited process* as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Process Settings]

Click on the newly created process to see the defined workitem types. It is here that you may disable *Product Backlog Item* and add *User Story* as a new workitem type.

[image: Workitem Types]

Then you may switch over to the `Backlog levels` tab and edit the **Requirement backlog** section to configure the User Story work item type as a backlog level and set it to be the default work item type, as shown below:

[image: Edit Backlog Level]

After this is saved, you should be able to emulate the workflow you desired: **Epic > Feature > User Story > Task**.

I tried the above mentioned steps on a Test project I had, and voila, was able to get the following structure created as under:

[image: TestScrumWorkflow]

Please try and check if this fits your requirement.

Hope this helps!

References for additional reading:

- [Scrum process work item types and workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?view=azure-devops)
- [Inherited objects versus custom objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#inherited-objects-versus-custom-objects)